# POST relation in strapi

Tags: node.js, api, next.js, postman, strapi

I have a strapi project and A single users have relation a single profile. For example if we using postman to get a single user it have response

```
[
{
    "id": 45,
    "username": "test",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "provider": "local",
    "confirmed": true,
    "blocked": false,
    "createdAt": "2022-07-18T08:50:43.642Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-07-18T08:50:43.642Z",
    "profile": null
}
```

]
As you can see a user have a profile but have a `null` value. So when I tried to post a profile in strapi api `http://localhost:1337/api/profiles?populate=*` with body of json like this

```
{
"data" : {
"name": "fgh",
"address": "jksdjkdjs",
"phone": "345345",
"email" : "test@gmail.com" /// I tried to add this but the response is 500 internal server error
}}
```

It worked and `status 200 ok` but it didn't get the relation of the email from user

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 12,
    "attributes": {
        "name": "fghdff",
        "address": "jksdjkdjs",
        "phone": 34534235,
        "createdAt": "2022-08-05T13:48:29.548Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-08-05T13:48:29.548Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-08-05T13:48:29.547Z",
        "email": {
            "data": null
        }
    }
},
"meta": {}}
```

Any Idea how to post a relation in strapi? I tried to read docs or strapi forum but no one counter this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone facing how to POST relation in strapi we can use the ID of the User. For example to post and connect in my question is

```
{   
"data" : {
    "name": "dayee",
    "address": "jksdjkdjs",
    "phone": "34534235",
    "email" : 77 // Post relation using ID
}}
```